# How do I create an object from array of objects using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
const arr = [{name:"abc", age:10},{name:"xyz", age:20},{name:"asd", age:12}];
```

Need output as:

```
{abc: {age:10}, xyz: {age:20}, asd: {age: 12}}
```

Comment: Share your code please you tried and it didn't work

Comment: Notice, that if all the names are not unique, the object structure you want looses some data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to iterate through all the array items and build a new object with the desired format:

```js
const arr = [{name:"abc", age:10},{name:"xyz", age:20},{name:"asd", age:12}];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, currentValue) => {
  // grab the name in a separate variable and keep the rest of the object in another using object destructuring
  const { name, ...rest } = currentValue;
  // use the name as a key in the result and assign the rest as the value
  acc[name] = rest;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer only works if all objects have unique names. If there are any duplicates, some of the values WILL be overwritten.

```js
const arr = [{name:"abc", age:10},{name:"xyz", age:20},{name:"asd", age:12}];
const newObject = {};

arr.forEach(item => {
  const name = item.name;
  delete item.name;
  newObject[name] = item;
})

console.log(arr)

console.log(newObject)
```

Comment: Why do you modify the original? Also you were missing a `)`

Answer (score 1):

Is this enough for what you want to do?

```js
const arr = [
  { name: "abc", age: 10 },
  { name: "xyz", age: 20 },
  { name: "asd", age: 12 },
];

function transform(data) {
  let newObject = {};
  for (let element of data) {
    newObject = { ...newObject, [element.name]: { age: element.age } };
  }
  return newObject;
}

console.log(transform(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [
  { name: "abc", age: 10 },
  { name: "xyz", age: 20 },
  { name: "asd", age: 12 },
];

const output = {};

arr.forEach((a) => {
  output[a.name] = {
    age: a.age,
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

Output

```
{ abc: { age: 10 }, xyz: { age: 20 }, asd: { age: 12 } }
```